# Linked to a valid external css but display was not styled

Tags: css, django

My project forum structures its files as:

```
forum
├── __init__.py
├── settings.py
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── bootstrap.min.css
├── templates
│   └── index.html
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

I linked "bootstrap.min.css" to `index.html` like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Forum Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <h2>Coding Journey</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">Concepts
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">Reading</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">Coding</div>
      </div>

    </div> <!--container-->

  </body>
</html>
```

However, when open the `index.html` in browser, it's not styled at all.

What's the problem with my operations?

[image]

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
)
```

Comment: post your `settings.py`, the section where you have defined the path of static files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your settings file, it is probably because you're passing just a string as the list/tuple of strings....
I think you mean to do

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),  # notice the comma here
)
```

This is one of the problems with Python that you need to add an explicit comma to differentiate between a tuple and just parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

you can find more detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)

```
setting.py 
STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")]

urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns[
'your url'
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```